# Get a dummy slf4j logger?

Tags: java, slf4j, null-object-pattern

Can I get a dummy logger from slf4j? (Think the null object design pattern.) If so, can someone provide an example? Or will I have to implement a custom logger if I want to do that?

I'm hoping to write a function along the lines of

```
private Logger logger;
static Logger nullLogger;

static {
    nullLogger = getMeADummyLogger();
}

public Logger getLogger() {
    return this.logger == null ? nullLogger : this.logger;
}

// then, elsewhere:
this.getLogger().info("something just happened");
```

and not get a `NullPointerException` on that last line if no logger has been set.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use [`NOPLogger`](http://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/helpers/NOPLogger.html):

```
return this.logger == null ? NOPLogger.NOP_LOGGER : this.logger;
```