# How can we disable the hibernate logs?

Tags: java, hibernate

I am working on Hibernate project, But I have to write the logs into a file then both will combined(Hibernate log added in file) How can we disable the hibernate logs.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.1</version> 
</dependency>
```

Comment: Wouldn't setting the log level of org.hibernate to NONE solve this?

Comment: .. or better to ERROR

Comment: No,  I've used this but its not working for me  java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.hibernate").setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.OFF);

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311408/turning-off-hibernate-logging-console-output

Comment: I've seen already, Currently In my system (Project logs+Hibernate logs) are printed in same file whenever I turn off the logs then both logs are disabled but I have to do that project logs should be printed and only Hibernate logs turn off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me..

`static {
        // Initialized log4j2 Property and disable hibernate log
        Configurator.initialize("LOGS", "Projects/log4j.properties");
        Configurator.setLevel("org.hibernate", org.apache.logging.log4j.Level.OFF);
    }`

Comment: what is Configurator? can you please explain?

Answer (score 0):

Here are two approaches:

1. Setting the logging level to NONE should turn off all logging.
2. Since Hibernate uses the `slf4j` facade, you should be able to use the `NOPLogger`; see [Get a dummy slf4j logger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5389137/get-a-dummy-slf4j-logger).

   Replace the `log4j-core` dependency with this:

   ```
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
       <artifactId>slf4j-nop</artifactId>
       <version>1.7.30</version>
    </dependency>
   ```

---

> I've used this but its not working for me:
>
> ```
> java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.hibernate")
>                         .setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.OFF);
> ```

Yea, that won't work.  According the the dependency in your question, you have selected the `log4j` as the backend.  The code snippet above is configuring the `java.util.logging` logger ...

Look at the javadocs for the log4j classes.